# Making chat server (Chat server's .NET service and Chat client's iOS applications) with Window service or WCF

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to build a chat server but i don't know i should use Window service or WCF? Numbers of client of my chat service not a lot, it's about 30 to 40 (Exactly, it's not a chat server, it just a server use to send/recieve data to/from client in local network). Should i use Window service or WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is your choice.